# Host a sql server-like process within an application

Tags: sql-server

Hello
Is there a way to host *something like* a SQL server process within an application. Say within an ASP .NET Global Application object?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "something like a SQL Server process"  What part of a SQL Server process do you want your gizmo to be like?

Comment: Well, I'd want to have the basic db operations (INSERT, SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE) be available.

Comment: What happens when your app restarts?  Should data be persisted?  (HttpApplicationState is cleared each time the app restarts).  Are you more or less looking for a light-weight DB?

Comment: Why not take SQL Server Compact Edition? "SQL CE runs in-process with the application which is hosting it.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using either a file-based database (like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)) or SQL Server CE for this job.